# I lose access to my server when I run a process intensive program

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface

I have a dedicated root public server, and whenever I run a process intensive program, something like proof of work that uses the CPU intensively (I use 4 out of the 8 CPUs in that machine), I just completely lose access to the server (anything with network interface access is lost, including sshd, apache, and others). I have to force restart it through the provider's control panel to gain access again.

I also tried the make the niceness with lowest priority possible, 19. That didn't help.

When I do the restart, there's nothing wrong in the logs (/var/log/syslog). Everything shows to be normal, until the point of restarting.

Is there something else I can do to investigate this problem?

Answer (score 0):

[Serial console](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Working_with_the_serial_console) logs are your best bet. See if the control panel provides such a thing. If not, a screenshot of the frozen machine may contain useful information, too. [Netconsole](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netconsole) is more limited, but can be adequate in some cases.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that happens. One workaround is to run the offending process with nice, lowering their priority (and thus freeing up some cycles for logging in). But if they also use lots of memory, they may crowd out the programs required to login, and thus leave you in the same bind.

Comment: As I mentioned, I already tried `nice -19`. The program doesn't even take 10 MB of memory... Is there anything else that can be done? It seems this is some kind of flaw in the system.